# Am I using indexof correctly?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to use indexof to tell me if a string appears on page.

The function below should cycle through all checkboxes (name="comment") in my form checking for each checkbox's value within the rest of the document (only because I can't figure out how to search just one span).  If the string value is found to exist elsewhere on the page, that checkbox will change css style.

```
function loop() {

var comment=document.forms[0].comment;
var ii;

for (ii=0;ii<comment.length;ii++)  {
    str=comment[ii].value;
    id = comment[ii].id;

if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(str) !=-1)
{
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that all checkboxes turn "hidden".  I thought the problem was the checkbox finding its own value in the HTML, but the same happens when I search for nonsense.

Am I using indexof incorrectly?  Can anyone point out how and where?  I don't want to use window.find.

To elaborate:
Checkbox 1 value is "A IS FOR APPLE".  Check the page for the string "A IS FOR APPLE".  If found, make checkbox 1 hidden.  Go to checkbox 2 and repeat.

Comment: `indexOf` will return `-1` if the string is **not** found. Otherwise it will return the position it found the string at (can also be `0`). I would say your approach is questionable. Any time you want to do `innerHTML` you have to wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Side note: `innerHTML` always returns a string, so using `toString()` on it is unnecessary.

Comment: Side note 2: Don't do it this way!!! *"If the string value is found to exist elsewhere on the page, that checkbox will change css style"* That's just horrible.

Comment: Do you want to search in HTML or in text? meaning, if the checkbox value is "p", should a `<p>` tag match it? Also to search in just one span, use `document.getElementById("theSpanID").innerHTML`

Comment: :( *removed for being stupid*

Comment: *"...within the rest of the document (only because I can't figure out how to search just one span)..."* Get a reference to the span element, and then use `innerHTML` on the span.

Comment: @briansol: `Array#indexOf` has nothing whatsoever to do with `String#indexOf`. IE doesn't have any issues with the function the OP is using, and never has.

Comment: Haha thanks, all.  Can you suggest a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: @user3283304 I think the question is, what are you trying to achieve? Once we understand that, we can probably come up with a better way. However using the `getElementById` on the span will already be a LOT faster. And removing the `toString` as suggested will help too.

Comment: @dman2306  My goal is to search the page (really a span) for the unique string value of each checkbox in a form.  Each would be a fairly long and unique string of text.  If the value is found, then that checkbox should turn invisible (so I know its value already exists in the span).  Is that enough information or should I elaborate?

Comment: @user3283304 ok but again I ask, are you trying to search **html** or **text**?

Comment: @dman2306 Oh!  Text.  Sorry.

Comment: Ok, and can you provide the HTML for the span you want to search inside?

Comment: The span is a generic span filled with text content created by a PHP by and inserted with AJAX.  So, just: <span id="txtHint"></span>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what are you trying to do, I think a better approach should be something like this:

```
function loop() {

  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var span = document.getElementsById("txtHint");

  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    //Let's check only the checkbox with the name comment
    if(inputs[i].name == "comment" && inputs[i].value == span.innerText) {
          inputs[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }  
  }
```

Comment: The text I want to search is inside one span.

Comment: Also this assumes he wants to search all checkboxes on the page. His original only was searching inside forms[0]. If there are additional forms, this won't work properly.